# how can stub input using rspec 3

Tags: ruby, rspec

the method in question:

```
  def first_question
    puts "Do you know how to play? (yes or no)\n"
    answer = STDIN.gets.chomp.downcase.to_i
    return answer
  end
```

the spec I currently have:

```
  context "first_question" do
    it 'returns the answer' do
      expect{@game.first_question}.to output("Do you know how to play? (yes or no)\n").to_stdout
      allow(@game.first_question).to receive(:gets).and_return('yes')
      expect(@game.first_question).to be == "yes"
    end
  end
```

I want to test that the method displays the puts and receives a gets and returns that answer. How can I do this in Rspec 3?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like this:

```
context "#first_question" do
  let(:input) { "Yes\n" }

  before do
    allow(Kernel).to receive(:puts)
    allow(STDIN).to receive(:gets).and_return(input)
  end

  it 'outputs a question'
    first_question

    expect(Kernel).to have_received(:puts).with(
      'Do you know how to play? (yes or no)'
    ).once
  end

  it 'asks for input' do
    first_question

    expect(STDIN).to have_received(:gets).once
  end

  it 'returns the sanitized input' do
    expect(first_question).to eq 'yes'
  end
end
```

Please not that this silences all output done with `puts` while this test runs. I is a better solution to stub `puts` only on the object your are testing. I do not know what class you spec, but cn be done like `allow(Questionaire).to_receive(:puts)` instead of stubbing `Kernel`.

Answer (score 1):

to mock gets on STDIN use:

```
expect(STDIN).to receive(:gets).and_return('yes')
```

to check puts you can try

```
expect(@game).to receive(:puts).with("Do you know how to play? (yes or no)\n")
```

PS: .to_i won't have the expected result in your method!